# Mongo DB : Update document when another document gets inserted in to Collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I wanted to update one specific document based on selection criteria from collection 1 when another document gets inserted into collection 2. So collection 2 is the child of collection 1 which keeps multiple records against a document from collection 1. Documents in collection 1 has a field "ChildCount" and I wanted to increment this field when any document gets inserted into collection 2

```
Col 1  : ID,Name,ChildCount
Col 2  : ID,Col1_Doc_Id,Details{}
```

So is it possible to run some sort of process in background or do I need to do it manually from application end point .
Please suggest

Comment: It's generally manual. There is no such thing as "triggers" if that was your line of thinking. This sort of "write to parent whilst adding child" operation is exactly what "embedded documents" are for though, so you might want to think on the design. Having the data all in the one document counters the specific problem. Which is why you are not using an RDBMS, is it not?

Comment: ok . I will go for manual process from application end . Actually my col 1 contains multiple documents of each item type . Initially I thought of embedding ItemType and ItemDetails in one document but in case ItemType change I have to update all child ItemDetail documents with the change .